# How to get the name of a method in a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to get the specific name of the current method in Ruby?

Example:

```
class Pages
  def home
    @title = self.name
  end
end
```

I want to get this result:

```
p = Pages.new
p.home # it must print "home"
```

Comment: I edited your question for language and grammar. I hope I got you what you want. If not, you can edit the question yourself to clarify.

Comment: thank mr joelparkerhenderson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, What you're looking for is the variable "`__method__`" which should return a symbol representing the current method. That variable is in scope whenever you are inside a method.

To get the variable as a string: `__method__.to_s`

Comment: utilizing method to_s for name of a method resulted "nil"